# Inline Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, inline

I've been trying to set up an inline datepicker in my project. And I ended up having empty fields that don't save the selected date.

So here's how it looks:

[image]

When clicking an 'Empty' link I'm getting an empty input and I can edit text but no calendar displayed.

[image]

If I click slightly lower than this editing area, the calendar appears and I'm able to select a date.

[image]

[image]

Then after refreshing the page everything's getting into initial position. So what am I doing wrong?

This is my view file:
**views/tasks/index.html**

```
<h3>Tasks database</h3>

<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= render 'form' %>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <td>
    <%= sortable "title", "Title" %>
  </td>

<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
<tr class='tasks' id="task_<%= task.id %>">

  <td>
    <%= link_to user_task_path(current_user, task.id), method: :delete,
     data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <% end %>

    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="task" data-model='task' data-name='title'
      data-url="/users/<%= current_user.id %>/tasks/<%= task.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
      <i><%= task.title %></i>
    </a>

     <a href="#" data-type='date' id='task' data-format ='dd-mm-yyyy' placement='right' data-xeditable="true" data-pk="task" data-model='task' data-name='title'
      data-url="/users/<%= current_user.id %>/tasks/<%= task.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
      <%= task.review_date %>
     </a>
  </td>

</tr>

<% end %>

</table>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#task').editable({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        viewformat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        datepicker: {
                weekStart: 1
           }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```